# Prime character residues

Tags: number-theory

For a quadratic character $ \chi \bmod m $, define $\displaystyle r_\chi(n)=\sum_{d\,\mid\, n}\chi(d) $. I would like to prove that

$$\sum_{n \leq m }\frac{r(n)}{n} \ll \frac{m}{\varphi(m)}\exp \Big( 2 \sum_{\substack{p \,\leq\, m \\ p \text{ prime} \\ \chi(p)\,=\,1}} \frac{1}{p} \Big) $$

I think I found a characterization of $ r_{\chi} $:

$$r_\chi(n)=\prod_{p^e\,\|\,n}(1+\chi(p)+\cdots+\chi(p)^e)$$

$$ r_\chi(n)=\begin{cases}0
& \text{if } \exists \text{ prime } p\mid n \text{ such that }  e_p(n) \text{ is odd and } \chi(p)=-1 \\ 
\tau(n) & \text{if  all the primes } p\mid n \text{ are residues} \\ 
\tau(\frac{n}{m}), & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases} $$

Here $\tau(n)$ represents as usual, the number of divisors of $n$ and $\displaystyle m= \!\!\! \prod_{\substack{p^e\,\|\,n \\  \ \chi(p)=1}}p^e $.

I apologize for my bad latex skills and would appreciate any comments, ideas and sugestions. Thank you very much!

Comment: you already know that $\displaystyle\sum_{n < x} \frac{r_\chi(n)}{n} \sim L(1,\chi) \ln(x)$ ?

Comment: user1952009, I don't know if that holds true and if so, how can I use it to prove the statement?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty r_\chi(n) n^{-s} = (\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n) n^{-s})(\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}) = L(s,\chi) \zeta(s)$. if $\chi$ is non-principal then $L(1,\chi)$ is finite and non-zero. finally use the Perron formula $\sum_{n=1}^\infty r_\chi(n) n^{-s}  = s \int_1^\infty (\sum_{n \le x} r_\chi(n)) x^{-s-1} dx$, that $L(s,\chi) \zeta(s) \sim \frac{L(1,\chi)}{s-1}$ when $s \to 1^+$ and you get $\sum_{n \le x} r_\chi(n) \sim L(1,\chi)\ x$ and $\sum_{n \le x} \frac{r_\chi(n)}{n} \sim L(1,\chi) \ln x$

Comment: finally, use the PNT to get $\sum_{p \le x, \chi(p) = 1} \frac{1}{p} \sim  C\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} \sim C\ln\ln x$ with $C = \frac{1}{\phi(q)}$ if $\chi$ is primitive non-principal modulo $q$, and conclude